# The symbol tilde (~) in CSS, doesn't work for me

Tags: html, css

I want to add zoom effect for my div element, when the link section hovered.

```css
.box {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: green;
}
.link:hover ~ .box{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" src=""></div>

<a class="link" href="#">
   <p class="projectTitles">link</p>
</a>
```

as you can see, it doesn't work.

Comment: It works perfectly as designed; but there is no previous-sibling selector.

Comment: hmm.. thanks I got it. so, is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: I was just writing an answer when the question was closed (perhaps, prematurely). Yes, there is something you could try: reverse the order of the elements in your HTML, wrap them into a div, then use `flex-direction: column-reverse` on the wrapper to display them properly. See: https://pastebin.pl/view/d09374c4

Comment: @FilipMilovanović - Wow what a trick! thank you so much, It worked!